# Alarm Clock for iOS

Tags: ios, nsdate, uilocalnotification, uidatepicker

I tried to re-write the following tutorial under Xcode 4.6.3 - http://vimeo.com/29824336

But I have the problem that at around 24:00 my code is not bringing up the alarm:

```
-(void) scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate:(NSDate *)fireDate
{
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    notification.fireDate = fireDate;
    notification.alertBody = @"Time to wake up!";
    notification.soundName = @"SNSD-Oh.caf";
    NSLog(@"Ring Ring Ring!");

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: notification];
}

- (IBAction) alarmSetButtonTapped:(id)sender
{    
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;

    NSString *dateTimeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: dateTimePicker.date];
    NSLog(@"Alarm Set Button tapped: %@", dateTimeString);

    [self scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate: dateTimePicker.date];
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Is your app in the foreground at 24:00? If the application is foremost and visible when the system delivers the notification, no alert is shown, no icon is badged, and no sound is played.

Comment: Are you sure your date has the correct timezone component?

Comment: @claireware thank you. That works. Now I receive a little pop-up from above. But I receive it two times? And no sound is playing.

Answer (score 0):

Your app must not be running in foreground when the notification fires.

If you want to play sound in foreground,you can use combination of `UIAlertView` and 'AvAudioPlayer'.

You can setup this code in

`-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification` delegate method of `AppDelegate.m`.

Feel free to ask further.